# How to export database from sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am making a Movies database for my University, and our instructor wants from us to give him what we have stored in the database so far.

So I want to know how can I extract the whole database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL Server Management Studio, go to the `Object Explorer` and then choose `Tasks > Generate Scripts` and follow the wizard.

[image]